# Optimal normal basis in Tower field construction

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

If I work over $GF(2^4)$, then the condition for the type I optimal normal basis holds, in fact $4+1=5$ is prime and $2$ is a primitive element in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. My question is about the existence of an optimal normal basis in case that one starts from $GF(2^2)$ and construct $GF(2^4)$ as quotient ring $\dfrac{GF(2^2)[x]}{<q(x)>}$ with $q(x)$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$.

For example, starting from $GF(2)$, one chooses $x^2+x+1$ as irreducible polynomial so that $GF(2^2)=\dfrac{GF(2)[x]}{<x^2+x+1>}$. Then, using polynomial basis one has $GF(2^2)=\{0,1,\alpha,1+\alpha\}$ with $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$. In this case, $\alpha$ and $1 + \alpha$ are optimal normal basis elements, in fact $\alpha^3=(1+\alpha)^3=1$ so that the normal basis $\{\alpha, 1+\alpha\}$ is also optimal. 
Then, if one chooses $x^2+x+\alpha^2$ as irreducible polynomial, one has $GF(2^4)=\dfrac{GF(2^2)[x]}{<x^2+x+\alpha^2>}$. I don't represent all the elements for simplicity: they are linear combination of, e.g., polynomial basis $\{1, \beta\}$ with $\beta^2=\beta+\alpha^2=\beta+\alpha+1$ with coefficients in $GF(2^2).$ In this case, is it possible to find an optimal normal basis? If yes, can you explain me how? I tried to compute all $16$ elements to the power $3$, but anyone returns $1$, except for $1$, $\alpha$ and $1+\alpha$. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know where.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen

The third roots of unit are $1, \alpha, \alpha+1$. In this case it is not possible to find an optimal normal basis due to the fact that the condition about primitivity of $4$ in $Z_3$ falls.

Comment: Exactly how are you calculating the third powers in $GF(16)=GF(4)[x]/\langle x^2+x+\alpha^2\rangle$? If $\beta=x+\langle x^2+x+\alpha^2\rangle$ is a zero of your irreducible polynomial then
$$\beta^2=\beta+\alpha+1$$
as you figured out. Therefore I get
$$\beta^3=\beta^2\cdot\beta=\beta^2+(\alpha+1)\beta=\alpha\beta+(\alpha+1)\neq1?$$ In other words the coefficients of $\beta^3$ with respect to the monomial basis $\{1,\beta\}$ are $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get it... To prove that an element of GF(2^4) is a 3rd root of unit, I first represent all the elements of that field w.r.t polynomial basis $\{1,\beta\}$
 and then I calculate the third power with the aim to get 1 as result, am I wrong? And any of the elements returns 1... maybe I am confused...

Comment: Hmm. Then I misunderstood. I got the impression that you thought you found too many third roots of unity. Anyway, the third roots of unity are in the subfield $GF(4)$ already. And they are exactly the elements $1,\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$. In other words, there are no other third roots of unity $GF(16)$. Did you expect to find some?

Comment: I don’t know why I thought I should get non-unit third roots of unit different from $ \alpha $ e $\alpha +1$ . So In that case, an optimal normal basis element is $\alpha$ So that I can put $\gamma =\alpha$ with $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$, and have an optimal normal basis of shape $\{\gamma,\gamma^4\}$?

Comment: If you set $\gamma=\alpha$, then $\gamma^4=\gamma$. In other words, you can't get a normal basis of $GF(16)$ over $GF(4)$ from third roots of unity, because those third roots of unity are all in the smaller field. Why did you think such a recipe would give you a normal basis?

Comment: I was reading this article about optimal normal basis 
https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X12000492/1-s2.0-S0022314X12000492-main.pdf?_tid=13fae0fc-fe90-11e7-8c3f-00000aacb361&acdnat=1516528222_f9c60fdfc56c24c99737ce2214168652


and when talk about the construction, it said that "Then the n nonunit (n + 1)th
roots of unity are linearly independent and they form an optimal normal basis  of Fqn over Fq"

Comment: In my case, $q=2^2$ and $n=2$. The $3$rd non-unit roots of unit are $\alpha$ and $\alpha +1$ and $4$ is primitive in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. So, which is an optimal normale base?

Sorry for these continuous questions ...

Comment: $4$ is not primitive in $\Bbb{Z}_3$. We have $4=1$ in that residue class ring. The primitivity is essentially. If $q$ generates a group of order $\ell<n+1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{n+1}$, then the roots of order $n+1$ belong to the smaller field $\Bbb{F}_{q^\ell}$, and cannot form a desired basis for $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Comment: *Primitive modulo* $n+1$ means that the smallest positive exponent $\ell$ such that $q^\ell\equiv1\pmod{n+1}$ is $\ell=n$. $2$ is primitive modulo $5$, because none of $2^1,2^2,2^3$ have remainder $1$ modulo $5$. $4^1$ has remainder $=1$ modulo $3$, so $4$ is not primitive modulo $3$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. So, to respond at both your "different" comments:
1) So, I can construct an optimal normal basis only starting from a prime field, right? I was misled by the fact that the definition of the article takes $q$ as power of prime, but now that I think of it, it does not say that the base field is not a prime field. 
2) You're right... I don't know how I could have made this mistake :O ... sorry

Comment: The article you linked to gave a definition of an optimal normal basis over a non-prime field that naturally extends the one I was familiar with. So I was wrong about that. Anyway, the primitivity was your  mistake. You can wrap this up by posting an answer explaining the mistake. Or not. Strictly your call :-)

Comment: So, the possibility to have an optimal normal basis in this case falls because it does not respect the condition of primitivity of the element $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I can search for a normal basis, but not optimal. An optimal base exists if I start from $GF(2)$ and choose an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$. In that case, $2$ in primitive in $Z_5$ and $5$ is prime.  Right? :) Thank you, now I edit my answer!

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$ Not all extensions have optimal normal basis. IIRC the handbook of cryptography describes an algorithm for finding a relatively good normal basis for large extensions of $GF(2)$. I'm afraid I don't know the state of the art.